# Remove highlight on first row in Datagridview

Tags: vb.net

I have a VB.net form application that works wonderfully. Once I do my print function it prints my "slip" which is my datagridview.

But when it prints it shows the first rows item as highlighted.

Is there a way to turn that off? I have looked through the properties and have no found anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
Private Sub datagridview1_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles datagridview1.SelectionChanged
  datagridview1.ClearSelection()
End Sub
```